# Check if a file exists in the documents directory

Tags: iphone

How can one check if a file exists in the documents directory by a specific name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
BOOL isMyFileThere = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myFilePath];
```

Check in [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Documentation .

Answer (score 5):

[`-[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CHDDDDJG)

Answer (score 4):

```
BOOL result = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileLocationofDocumentDirectory];

if(result ==YES)
{
NSLog(@"File present");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"File Not present");
}
```